# Screen sharing with windows 8.1 - observe windows screen on mac

Tags: macos, windows, remote-desktop, screen-sharing

Here are already some questions about how to connect to mac's screen from windows, like:

- [screen sharing from Windows to Mac over LAN](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/137283/screen-sharing-from-windows-to-mac-over-lan)
- [Screen Sharing from windows to mac with no software on the windows computer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/101505/screen-sharing-from-windows-to-mac-with-no-software-on-the-windows-computer)

I'm looking for a reverse way. My wife got a new windows 8.1 notebook, and i'm looking for a way how to

- connect to her notebook from my Mac
- observe what she doing and allow remote assistence from my MAC
- in short - the same functionality as the `/System/Library/CoreServices/Applications/Screen\ Sharing.app` does with another mac. (e.g. vnc://... )

What i need to install and/or configure in the windows notebook to got the ability **share** the windows 8.1 screen, e.g. what allows me doing the following:

```
$ smbutil lookup wifebook
Got response from 192.168.1.13
IP address of wifebook: 192.168.1.13
$ open vnc://192.168.1.13
```

Any ideas?

(ps: while i'm pretty familiar with UNIX like systems, i'm totally windows noob & ignorant)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple of options come to mind. You can try both and see which works best for you.

1) you can install [VNC for Windows](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=VNC%20for%20windows) (there are several versions) on her machine

Most are free and should work with the OSX vnc client application. I haven't use it so I can't say more. As long as they on the same network you should not have any problems. Over the internet, things get complicated...

2) install a free (for personal use) application like [TeamViewer](https://www.teamviewer.com/).

I prefer Teamviewer as it is simpler and it will work from anywhere in the world with a semi decent connection. There are several other applications like this out there but I've used it for years and I've come to trust it.

The other good thing about TeamViewer is that once her machine has it installed (and password protect it), it will get an numeric ID that should not change. Open an account with TeamViewer.com and save her ID there. Then anywhere in the world you can find her machine and share her screen. Neat no?

[image: TeamViewer]

Hope that helped.

Comment: As i said in another comment: TeamViewer is nice, but (as far as i know) for each session is needed to run teamviewer on the windows and this is "too much work" for my wife :) ;) - going to check some "VNC" for windows and will report back...

Comment: For best security, yes but you can also install it as a service so that it is always waiting for connection, with or without approval.

Comment: Going to try it immediately - if will work, accepting this answer. ;) +1 for now :) thanks.

Answer (score -1):

you can install Microsoft remote desktop for mac, this app can access the windows pc desktop remotely. https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/microsoft-remote-desktop/id715768417?mt=12

Comment: Hm, just tried it and it says: _Unable to connect to remote PC. Please verify Remote Desktop is enabled, the remote PC is turned on and available on the network, and then try again._ Probably need something setup/enable on the windows... could you please extend your answer with more details?

Comment: You can't screen share with MRD - logging in with RD will log the existing user out. TeamViewer would be a better bet.

Comment: @Tetsujin - TeamViewer is nice, but (as far as i know) need for each session is need to run teamviewer on the windows and this is "too much work" for my wife :) ;)

Comment: TeamViewer can just be set to run at login, no user-action required once set up initially. For what you want I'm certain it's the best option. We use it at work to access things like interactive touch screens in colleges, where there *is* no real 'remote user'. Set & forget on-site once.

Comment: @Tetsujin - SURE? If yes (and going to check it immediately) - if is enough setup it once - it will be probably the best option. Thank for the help.

Comment: yes, as Vic says, slightly less secure, but can be set as a service, always-on.

Comment: Also has the advantage that it's easier to punch through a firewall, as both host & client are 'looking out' rather than something 'getting in'